# Are MSP patches supported on Windows 7 RC?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, crm

I have an MSP patch file for Microsoft Dynamics that runs fine on Windows XP, but fails to run on Windows 7.  The file launches (with Microsoft Installer) but then fails and gives the error:  A fatal error has occurred.  The Microsoft Dynamics GP installation has ended prematurely.  Click Finish to exit the installation.

I've tried turning off UAC, and running the file locally, but I still get the same error.  It might be a bug, of course, but if anyone has run an MSP patch file successfully in Windows 7, that would be helpful to know.  Or are there any other things I might try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.  The trick was to first disable UAC, and then to install the .NET Framework 1.1 SP1.